# Who is this six-armed blonde female character?

Tags: character-identification

[image]

My brother has this figurine of a six-armed woman with blonde hair. It also has the numbers 101 on its back. I have no idea whether it is from a game or show. Does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: Thats from the game Fallout, though it is a variation on the Vault Boy character. Possibly one of the perk tree characters?

Comment: @Kimmer: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. Please do so. :)

Comment: Why not ask your brother? Lol Talking still works in today's digital age. Anyway, still liked the question and the photos

Answer (score 40):

This depicts the "[Black Widow](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Widow)" perk for Fallout.

[image: Black widow]

Specifically, this is the [Funko mini figurine](http://www.monkeydepot.com/Mini_Figure_Funko_Fallout_Black_Widow_Perk_p/fkl0356.htm).

You can see it being unboxed (and therefore more 3D) in the following clip around 3 minutes 13 seconds in:

Comment: Good catch, +1. I blame Google for not finding this when I searched for `vault-girl six hands` :)

Comment: :) Yeah. I found it looking at the Vault-Girl entry and noticing that it appeared in some exclusive perks. From there, Black Widow seemed like a good match.

Comment: I actually work at a place that distributes Funko items, im ashamed i didnt spot that. Nice one.

Comment: Note if you've never played the game: that is not actually a character in the game, it's literally just a drawing shown on the perk-screen _(she has 6 arms only because spiders have 8 legs and the perk is named 'Black Widow')_.  What an obscure reference, I love it!

Comment: @Gallifreian Try again - Google now shows this question, and thus answer, as the top result. :D

Answer (score 10):

Looks awfully similar to the [Vault Boy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_Boy) from the [Fallout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_3) series.

Vault Boy is a mascot character of the Fallout series. In Fallout 3 it also appears as a perk tree character, as pointed out by Dpeif. You can collect those bobble-heads for your collection, although I've never seen a female one before.

Number 101 is the number of the [Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_101) where the protagonist of Fallout 3 hails from.

[image]